# ERROR: The symbol "(" was substituted for "VARCHAR2" to continue

Tags: plsql

I am trying to compile this package body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY package_1 AS
PROCEDURE procedure_1 (P_HOST IN VARCHAR2, P_USER IN VARCHAR2, P_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT HOSTNAME, USERS, PS_NAME 
INTO P_HOST, P_USER, P_NAME
FROM PS_COLLECT
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( 
    SELECT HOSTNAME, USERS, PS_NAME
    FROM PS_MASTER
    WHERE PS_MASTER.HOSTNAME = PS_COLLECT.HOSTNAME 
    AND PS_MASTER.USERS = PS_COLLECT.USERS 
    AND PS_MASTER.PS_NAME = PS_COLLECT.PS_NAME
 );
END procedure_1;
END package_1;
```

But I am getting this error

```
The symbol "(" was substituted for "VARCHAR2" to continue.
```

I am a newbie int PL/SQL..please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't expect this to cause the exact error you're seeing, but one definite problem with your code is that you are specifying `IN` mode for the parameters, but then trying to assign values to them inside the procedure.  It looks like you should change the mode to `OUT` for all three parameters (in both the header and the body).

If that alone does not resolve your issue, I suggest posting the modified text of both the CREATE PACKAGE and CREATE PACKAGE BODY statements.